# Why "Update from Repository" option is Disabled?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

**Update from Repository** option is disabled, when I try to update a file from Clearcase Repositary (`Team->Update from Repository`)

**Note**: I have ClearCase plugin installed in my Eclipse.

How can I enable this option?

Answer (score 0):

The help page "[Updating a resource in a ClearCase view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015913/clearcase-remote-client-update-from-repository-option-disabled) mentions:

> Before you can update a resource in a ClearCase view, you must be connected to the ClearCase server that supports the view, and the resource must already be loaded into the view.

So make sure this connection is active (See "[connect to a server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_connect_cc.htm)"), and that the file is indeed in a web view.

Comment: We are getting below error message when we tried to connect clearcase server. _The server cannot be contacted.  Please contact your system administrator.
(504)Unknown Host_

Comment: @user3887734 that is the first issue to solve, then. As long as the server cannot be resolved, nothing will work. did you try the IP address?